# Editing SharePoint home page for a publishing portal

Tags: publishing-site, anonymous-authentication

I am using SharePoint 2007 Server x64 on Windows Server 2008 x64. I create a new SharePoint web application with a new site collection at the root of the web application. I select the template "publishing portal" for the site collection. I have also enabled anonymous access.

Now the basic function is fine, except that I do not know how to change the first front page (i.e. the page showed to end users who have not logged in yet) of the site. Here is a screen snapshot. Any ideas how to edit this page?

[image: Publishing home page]

BTW: I have tried to edit the default.aspx after login but anonymous users could still see content like in the following list. How do I remove this for an anonymous user?

```
Enable anonymous access
You must enable anonymous access on the site collection for the forms authentication logon page to work from Office SharePoint Server. Contact your administrator to have anonymous access enabled in Central Administration and IIS.
Manage navigation
Change the navigation links in this site.
Go to master page gallery 
Change the page layouts and master page of this site collection.
Manage site content and structure
Reorganize content and structure in this site collection.
Set up multilingual support
Use the variations feature to manage multi-lingual sites and pages.
Add users to the Approvers and Members groups
Users in the Approvers group can publish pages, images, and documents in this site. Users in the Members group can create and edit pages, and they can upload images and documents, but they cannot publish the pages, images, or documents. Workflow is enabled in the Pages library, and content approval is enabled in the Documents and Images libraries.
```

Comment: I want to share knowledge here. Actually I have solved this issue, it is caused by the document is not approved by approvers yet. So, only the user who has updated document can see the updated content, and other users like (anonymous) can not see the content.

Comment: @George2: Thanks for sharing. As you have answered this question, why don't you add it as an answer below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In the system.web section of you web.config you can add the following section (I assume your using forms authentication).
This should redirect all unauthenticated users to a specific page.

Chris
http://chrisbarba.wordpress.com